# SQL syntax for join

Tags: sql

Suppose I have two tables:

**Table A** has information about the stock holdings of different investment funds:

```
FundID   FundType   StockID   Weight
1        Small      A         0.50
1        Small      B         0.50
2        Small      B         0.25
2        Small      C         0.75
3        Large      A         1.00
4        Large      D         1.00
```

**Table B** summarizes the weight each stock has within each type of fund:

```
FundType  StockID  AvgWeight
Small     A        0.25
Small     B        0.375
Small     C        0.375
Large     A        0.5
Large     D        0.5
```

(Note that if a stock isn't listed for a fund, then the weight is assumed to be 0.)

I want to create a new table (with SQL) that has, for each `FundID` in Table A, all stocks that are held by any fund of the same type:

**Desired results table:**

```
FundID   FundType   StockID   Weight   AvgWeight
1        Small      A         0.50     0.25
1        Small      B         0.50     0.375
1        Small      C                  0.375
2        Small      A                  0.25
2        Small      B         0.25     0.375
2        Small      C         0.75     0.375
3        Large      A         1.00     0.5
3        Large      D                  0.5
4        Large      A                  0.5
4        Large      D         1.00     0.5
```

Notice that *all* stocks that are held by *any* small fund (A, B, and C) are included for each small fund (FundID is 1 or 2). Similarly, all stocks that are held by *any* large fund (A and D) are included in the results for each large fund.

I think I need to do some kind of outer join, but have so far been unable to figure out the SQL syntax. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    ft.FundId
  , ft.FundType
  , fs.StockId
  , aa.Weight           --- or COALESCE(aa.Weight, 0) to display 0 and not NULL 
  , bb.AvgWeight
FROM 
        ( SELECT DISTINCT
              FundId
            , FundType
          FROM 
              TableA
        ) AS ft
    INNER JOIN
        ( SELECT DISTINCT
              FundType
            , StockId
          FROM 
              TableA
        ) AS fs 
            ON  fs.FundType = ft.FundType
    LEFT JOIN
        TableB AS bb
            ON  bb.FundType = fs.FundType
            AND bb.StockId = fs.StockId
    LEFT JOIN
        TableA AS aa
            ON  aa.FundId = ft.FundId
            AND aa.FundType = ft.FundType
            AND aa.StockId = fs.StockId
```

The `INNER fs LEFT JOIN bb` may be replaced with a simple `INNER JOIN bb`, if `TableB` has rows for all `(FundType, StockId)` combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason that a CROSS JOIN would not be appropriate to solve this?

It seems like the OP is asking for all the possible valid combinations between the two tables, which is the perfect reason to CROSS, is it not?